# Unhandled ASP.NET Errors - any logging available?

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

We've had an issue where a .NET error occured at the root of our application cluster that bypassed our error handling and was displaying the generic ASP.NET error message.

Is there anywhere to check to see these errors if it bypassed our logging of them? (Default .NET/IIS logging or anything?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to check the Application Event Viewer.

1. Right-click My Computer
2. Manage
3. Event Viewer
4. Application

The assumption here is that it bubbled up and didn't get caught anywhere.

Comment: Assumption yea, but nothing visible on the server. What we got was the generic ASP.NET error message. Edited the web.config because remoteonly wasn't turned on, and it started working. So I'm here trying to figure out what the error message actually said.

Comment: That message should be in the event viewer, I believe.

Comment: On one of my servers, every unhandled exception goes to the event viewer.  On another server, NONE of them do. Why this difference? What do I configure?

Comment: @RossPresser I have no idea. You should ask a new question on this site. I'm sure someone else can help you

Answer (score 2):

```
// Inside your logger constructor:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDomainUnhandledException);

// Then:
private void AppDomainUnhandledException(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Log as unhandled exception: e.ExceptionObject.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS7 you can add failed request tracing via IIS Manager.  See the following article for more information:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/