# See detail of "Server Error in '/' Application" in IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

My user report that he can't enter the web after he login to the web, and the page only display

> Server Error in '/' Application

Is there a way so I can see the detail of error in IIS Server, because I don't want to change the web.config to show the detail on a user's display

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled ASP.NET Errors - any logging available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036234/unhandled-asp-net-errors-any-logging-available)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ELMAH http://elmah.github.io/

You can add a DLL to your project, and configure a connection string in the web config. This will then log all errors to a database table, and show you what was happening at the time. It even tells you what was populated in textboxes on the page, which is useful for tracking what the user was typing at the time.

Failing that, try hooking into the `Application_Error` event in the global.asax file. Code I use is below and sends me an email whenever there is a server error:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when an error occurs

    Dim errorMessage As New StringBuilder
    Dim serverException As Exception = Server.GetLastError

    errorMessage.Append("<h1 style=""color:red;font-size:18pt;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;"">Server Error In NewmanWeb</h1>")
    errorMessage.Append("<hr width=""100%"" size=""1"" color=""silver"">")
    errorMessage.Append("<h2 style=""color:maroon;font-size:14pt;font-style:italic;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;"">" & serverException.Message & "</h2>")

    errorMessage.Append("<b>Exception Type:</b> " & serverException.GetType().ToString() & "<br />")

    If serverException.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
        errorMessage.Append("<b>Inner Exception Type:</b> " & serverException.InnerException.GetType().ToString() & "<br />")
        errorMessage.Append("<b>Inner Source: </b>" & serverException.InnerException.Source & "<br />")
        errorMessage.Append("<div style=""background:#ffffcc;font-family:Consolas,Monospace;padding:0.5em;font-size:11pt;""")
        errorMessage.Append("<pre>" & serverException.InnerException.Message & "</pre><br />")
        If serverException.InnerException.StackTrace IsNot Nothing Then
            errorMessage.AppendLine("<pre>" & serverException.InnerException.StackTrace & "</pre><br />")
        End If
        errorMessage.Append("</div><br />")
    End If

    If serverException.StackTrace IsNot Nothing Then
        errorMessage.Append("<b>Stack Trace: </b><br />")
        errorMessage.Append("<div style=""background:#ffffcc;font-family:Consolas;padding:0.5em;font-size:11pt;""")
        errorMessage.Append("<pre>" & serverException.StackTrace & "</pre>")
        errorMessage.Append("</div>")
    End If

    'Send email code here

    Server.Transfer("~/Error.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: in my situation right now, i can't add/delete anything to the web server. is there a way to see the log/detail using something that IIS provide?

Comment: Maybe you could update the answer with the new ELMAH url? It's http://elmah.github.io/

Comment: Cheers @ThomasArdal. Done now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to configure ELMAH, you could look the IIS logs. Maybe use something like [Log Parser](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2010/04/log-parser-22) from the IIS team to be able to write simple queries on top of your log files.

When that is done, I strongly recommend you to [set up ELMAH on your website](http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/). This saves you the next time you have a problem like this :)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point to determine which pages are causing the errors is using the following Log Parser query to extract the interesting lines **from IIS logs** :

```
::List of 500 errors
::------------------
logparser -i:IISW3C -rtp:-1 -o:NAT -headers:OFF -iw:ON "SELECT * FROM C:\inetpub\your-website.com\ex*.log TO c:\500Errors.txt WHERE (Extract_Extension(To_Lowercase(cs-uri-stem)) IN ('aspx')) AND cs-status >= 500)"
```

Additionally, to dig up more information about the **CAUSE**, you can query the **Windows Event Log** to look for a list of errors thrown by the 'WAS' process (Windows Activation Service) :

```
logparser.exe -i:EVT -rtp:-1 -o:NAT -headers:OFF -iw:ON "SELECT TimeGenerated,EventID,EventType,EventTypeName,EventCategory,EventCategoryName,SourceName,Strings,Data,Message,ComputerName,SID,EXTRACT_TOKEN( TO_LOWERCASE( RESOLVE_SID(Sid) ), 1, '\\') AS UsernameMessage FROM \\YourMachineName\System TO c:\WindowsEventLogWASerrors.txt WHERE TimeGenerated > '2016-07-12 00:00:00' AND EventType IN (1;2;4) AND SourceName = 'WAS' ORDER BY TimeGenerated DESC"
```

Just replace ***[YourMachineName]*** in the following query, and customize the Timeframe you are interested in (the ***[TimeGenerated]*** field).

NOTE : The meaning of the ***[EventType]*** values are the following :

- 1. Error
- 2. Warning
- 4. Information